# Adding routing to a legacy website

Tags: javascript, html, url-routing

I would like to get some advice regarding attemtping to enhance a web app I currently work on by adding routing

Currently our project layout structure looks like the following (We have hundreds of pages like this, HTML with a matching JS file with potentially 1000's line of code)

```
html
 - example1.html
 - example2.html

js
  -example1_functions.js
  -example2_functions.js

css (Sometimes each page has there own, Majority of the time they share a few between them)
  -example1_css
  -example2_css
```

Currently hard loads are always required between page switches, The majority of our pages are built using a main div with an ID in the html, Then the javascript will insert content into this div, E.G when visiting "mysite/example1.html"

```
Html (example1.html)
------

<script src="example1_functions.js"></script>

<!-- Potentially boiler plate HTML here for filters, Headers etc -->
<div id="dataContainer"> </div>
<script>
   $( document ).ready(function() {
      generateContent();
   });
</script>

JS (example1_functions.js)
------

function generateContent(){
   document.getElementByID("dataContainer").innerHTML = "Cool content";
}
```

And so on...

I've got experience using react router but I can't seem to find info on whether it's possible to easily convert such a legacy web app where the routes can't be so easily expressed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the time and resources to integrate a framework i would highly recommend angularjs it does come with an intergrated router but if you end up looking for some extended functionality i would recommend using angulars ui-router plugin instead of the built in one.

An example of our application using ui-router.

```
angular
    .module('app.globalSettings', ['ui.router'])
    .config(globalSettingsConfig);


globalSettingsConfig.$inject = [
    '$stateProvider'
];

function globalSettingsConfig($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('app.globalSettings', {
            url: '/globalSettings',
            views: {
                "content@app": {
                    controller: 'GlobalSettingsCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    templateUrl: 'app.cms/globalSettings/views/global-settings.html'
                }
            },
            data: {
                title: 'Global Settings'
            }
        });
}
```

project structure wise, seeing that you said you have thousands of lines of potential spaghetti code the component based structure is probably the best way.

for example

```
--> app
  --> post
    --> controllers
    --> directives
    --> services
    --> views
    --> module.js --> where ui-router info goes for component
--> app.js (this wires up all modules in your app)
```

a really easy way to play with this would be to install yeoman and you have generators which do most of the time consuming work for you!

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

here is a style guide if your into keeping code neat ;)

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

regarding integration into your current app it shouldn't be to hard but on the information you've given it sounds like it will be more time consuming than difficult.

UPDATE: if you're up to the task you should check out angular2 it's still quite early stages but seeing that you're going to restructuring your app it wouldn't hurt to do some research to see if you could benifit.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! We've had existing devs try to port to angular with no success so unfortunately it's a no go (An existing dev spent months getting no where with it, So would be impossible to get it signed off now), I can appreciate this may be helpful though so will have a further look

What i'm ideally is some way way I can make existing spaghetti code quickly into "components" until I have the time to refactor ( If ever :( ) and then create routes from them ( Without angular unfortunately, I could use react as we have parts of our system which use it ) using any routing library.

Comment: No problem. I see, that is a shame. after having a glance at this blog http://blog.andrewray.me/reactjs-for-stupid-people/ defo the blog for me as i have never touched react. it seems it will probably do what you need it to. What would make it a no go for me is that it's purely the V in MVC. but of course if it serves it's purpose for you then it's probably the best way to go. It seems you can integrate a framework behind it (like angular) in the future if that's what you decide to do for the extra feature like ajax.

Comment: I should add quickly though that if you are going to rebuild the structure you go for a component modular based approach to make it easier in the future for integration if wanted :)  no harm in building for the future!